# 'stdio.h' file not found, but I have this file at /usr/include/stdio.h

Tags: gcc

When I compile a package, I got the following error:

```
$ make
clang -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2  -I/usr/local/include/scws  -I. -I./ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/internal -I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o zhparser.o zhparser.c
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from zhparser.c:10:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server/postgres.h:46:
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3/include/server/c.h:59:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When I search this error online, all the online problems are not having header files at `/usr/include/`. But when I check the directory, it has many header files

```
$ ls -l /usr/include/stdio.h
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  16319 Jan 22  2018 /usr/include/stdio.h

$ ls -l /usr/include/ | wc -l
     266
```

So, what can I do in my case?

Thanks a lot.

**Edited:** I updated the error output. I just found out it had a warning too: `clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk'`, But I have `MacOSX10.13.sdk` instead because I am running MacOSX10.13. I have no ideas why it's looking for 10.14 sdk and not sure if this is the root cause or not.

Comment: What version of Xcode and gcc? clang does not look in /usr/include now https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes#3035624

Comment: @Mark thanks for the reply. My Xcode version is Version 9.4.1 (9F2000), xcode-select version 2349, Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2). I can not update XCode now due to weird apple app store problem. I am in China now. and iphone and MacOS has many weird things here. I don't want to talk about the upgrade issue now. For my current setup, how can I fix this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mark btw, I read that link. I don't have the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/`. Only `Library/`, `SDKs/`, `usr/` are inside `CommandLineTools/`.

Comment: Yep well you have a different Xcode so not the same. I would however reinstall the command line tool;s and run xcode-select

Comment: Also see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94476

Comment: @Mark btw, `xcode-select -p` returns `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`. Should I run `xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`? And I can not install anything in app store now. AppStore is just broken to me. I can only install apps via `brew` at the moment.

Comment: @Mark I have updated my question. I found a new warning msg to complain no `MacOSX10.14.sdk`, and I am not sure if this is the root cause or not. I am running MacOSX10.13 so I have 10.13 sdk instead of 10.14 and not sure why it's looking for 10.14. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark just let you know, I fix the problem by doing `sudo ln -s MacOSX.sdk/ MacOSX10.14.sdk`. I don't know why it looks for 10.14, but it works in this way...

Comment: Looks like you need to reinstall xcode

Comment: @Mark thanks for the tip. But I can not reinstall xcode now, because xcode has to be reinstalled by app store and can not use `brew install`. App Store is the worst installation manager I have ever used in my life. It doesn't provide any errors at all. Whenever I click something, it just hangs there forever. Error messages are friends, but app store refuses to give me any. It actually not hangs, it just seems it does not do anything at all. Sorry about the complain about app store. My experience with it is very bad.

Comment: @Mark hi, since nobody replied an answer yet and the problem is actually fixed. Would you like to provide an answer so that I can accept it as the final answer? Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: In this case you provided the fix and it is not one I recommend so you can answer

Comment: @Mark actually, I want to thank you for your time and help. It's my fault to not provide the complete output. I thought warning messages could be ignored so I didn't pay attention on it at the beginning. Anyway, if you don't want, I can write an answer and upvoted your comment instead. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the contents of the makefile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of the error message is from the warning message:

> clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk'

By checking SDKs directory:

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/
$ ls
MacOSX.sdk/      MacOSX10.13.sdk
```

So, to workaround the problem, it's either re-install xcode suggested by @Mark or create a symbolic link like the following:

```
$ sudo ln -s MacOSX.sdk/ MacOSX10.14.sdk
```